# A Database Error 1146 in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am using Codeigniter framework to build a website. I am receiving this error:

```
Error Number: 1146
Table 'users.ci_sessions' doesn't exist

SELECT `data` FROM `ci_sessions` WHERE `id` = '5e47bcb40c2954bd7329ff3fbcf253007a0563cc'

Filename: libraries/Session/drivers/Session_database_driver.php
Line Number: 166
```

Here is how session is defined:
In config.php:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_table_name'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = FALSE;
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';       // changed from file
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions'; // table name
//$config['sess_save_path'] = sys_get_temp_dir();
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
$config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;
```

In autoload.php:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session');
```

I have read https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html and followed all steps to properly access the session. Any suggestion on how to fix above error?

Comment: Do you have any table named `ci_sessions` in you database ?

Comment: @MdMahfuzurRahman Yes I do, just missed to paste it in the question: `$config['sess_table_name']  = 'ci_sessions';`

Comment: @Irfana Just a note that is the old and out dated user guide ellislab does not deal with codeigniter any more for version3 and 2 user guides please use these links http://www.codeigniter.com/docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you are mixing up both session drivers i.e `database` and `file`, so if you would like to use file driver read here the official documentation:
http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html#files-driver

And if you want to use database driver:
http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html#database-driver

Also i had encounter an strange bug in auto loading libraries.

Please add `session` driver before `database` driver in autoload array as:

`$autoload['libraries'] = array('session','database');`

Answer (score 2):

1. Note that the user-guide you've linked to is for version 2.2.0 and no longer official, while you're using 3.0.x.
2. Read the actual user guide here: http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html
3. Don't just tell us that you've read and followed all steps, but actually do it - you haven't created a `ci_sessions` table in the database. *The error message itself tells you this.*

Comment: I read the link you suggested and I believe I have followed the steps for using session library properly, if you believe what I have written in config is wrong, I would appreciate if you could correct me. Thanks. And I have edited the question.

Comment: Your `ci_sessions` table *don't exist* - that's what the error message says. You can't fix that by changing the config file.

Answer (score 1):

be careful with these parameters in `config.php`

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session'; //ci_session don't add 's' in last
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions'; //ci_sessions add 's' in last
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```